# (REOPENED) Reopen "How do I ask a recruiter for time to update my resume?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

Former title: "*Recruiter asks for resume, but mine is not ready*"

[How do I ask a recruiter for time to update my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71937)

---

This question got close votes for being unclear but the question, while basic, couldn't be clearer. We have plenty of similar questions that ask about ways to communicate something professionally and this is an especially common question. Many people may struggle with how to reply in this scenario and may end up delaying a response instead of replying because of it.

I also disagree with the downvotes on this one as the question is clearly worded and the OP asked an honest question.

---

Note: OP self-deleted shortly after the close vote came in, presumably due to the bad reception his question got. It has since been undeleted and was reopend shortly thereafter.

Comment: Too late, the author removed it.

Comment: @RichardU Monica commented on the question and I've voted to undelete.

Comment: 600 hundred more points to go 'til 10,000 :)

Comment: I would definitely support it being both undeleted and reopened.  It seemed to be a legitimate question.  The only reason I only commented rather than answer it was because I didn't have time just then to frame up a proper answer.

Comment: If it's undeleted, I'll vote to reopen

Comment: @JaneS Perhaps a mod could notify the OP that his question is being discussed here? I could comment on his other question on the main site but don't like abusing comments to PM.

Comment: I don't know if I can undelete the question at this point

Comment: Oh nevermind. It looks like someone else undeleted it.

Comment: I thought it was a pretty fair question. I think depending on their experience it's reassuring to know they can tell the recruiter the truth and ask them to wait whilst it's updated

Comment: I just cast the fifth reopen vote.

Comment: Thanks for reopening it everyone. @michaelsnowden I've dropped a bounty on the question to help it get some more attention.